# SQLBoiler ORM, how to execute raw query without binding?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, orm

I'm trying this ORM generator here https://github.com/vattle/sqlboiler

and I'm trying to execute a raw query using boil.SQL which I can see in their documentation. But when I do boil.SQL()., I see that the only methods available are Bind. Is there a way I can execute the query without binding to an object? Because I do not need any results back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boil.SQL()` returns a `*boil.Query`. You can pass this into `boil.ExecQuery()` if you don't care about the results.

```
q := boil.SQL("execute foo()")
_, err := boil.ExecQuery(q)
```

https://godoc.org/github.com/vattle/sqlboiler/boil#ExecQuery